# Why is my Python code adding a random single quotation mark when called from another file?

Tags: python, linux

My code is adding a single quotation mark at odd times.  It is only when I call it using another function and it screws up the array that I am trying to create

I have tried switching the code out for a regex expression.  This did not work, I tried changing my code to 'split' on ' ' and it produced the same result.  I looked for alternatives but unfortunately I can't do much with importing as this network has limited internet access.  It has to be in Python because other functions and code is relying on this (it does work in some other functions).

in somefile.py

```
Def createArrayFromString(strng, delim):
    Holder = ‘’
    arrStrng = []
    for x in strng:
       if not x.isspace():
          holder += x
       elif holder:
          arrStrng.append(holder)
          holder=’’
    if holder:
       arrStrng.append(holder)
    return arrString
```

called by a function that provides this (in another file):

```
for line in severalLinesInArray:
   createArrayFromString(x, ' ');
```

where x is something like this ~

```
'bunchofconfigcrap           severalWhitespaceslater   morecrap '
```

The expected result, which works in other files and when called inside the somefile.py is an array (well list) with several words and no empty values.
Example:

```
'The dog is in      the house' => 
['The', 'dog', 'is', 'in', 'the', 'house']
```

or without quotes, whatever.
What actually happens is this: `['The, dog, is, in, the, house']` 
(I believe there is not a quote at the end I can't remember (codes at work) and further processing provides an unexpected EOF...

I have tried printing it out to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your method has some issues, I assume these were caused by copy pasting it on SO, after making the modifications like changing the var names.. the example you say it fails on works correctly for me. My best guess is that the "SPACE" you see might be an invisible unicode char. Can you share a sample from the file itself ?

Comment: If you are running your code in an IDE which doesn't understand the said unicode char, it is converted to a default "boxed question mark"

Comment: your code will not work if it encounters this `data = u"The\u2800dog\u2800is\u2800in\u2800the\u2800house"`

Comment: @vin I am unable to share my code, I will look at the code in a couple days and tell you what I see...  I will also try the user belows answer.  Thanks!

Comment: So, I found out that my implementation was not working because of the way I was printing an output (an echo command, which was adding the single quotes), and my problem turned out to be elsewhere in the code thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Just use `list(filter(None, string.split(' ')))`.
It's purely built-in, it's smaller, it's faster, so why not?